# how to assign asp list item values to vb variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i tried assigning each list item to have an ID and i figured in the VB i could put like the ID.value =  my variable but apparently list items cant be assigned IDs in aspx.

ASP

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimePeriod" runat="server" CssClass="select" >
         <asp:ListItem Text="All Time" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Current Month" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Last Month" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

VB

```
     dim val1 as string  = "fifty points"
     dim val2 as string  = "twenty points"
     dim val3 as string  = "ten points"
```

I need to assign the value of the alltime listItem to the val1 in VB and so on and so forth and cant find an easy way.  i tried value='<%= val1 %>' but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a collection of values for the list:

```
Dim listValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
listValues.Add("fifty points", "All Time")
listValues.Add("twenty points", "Current Month")
listValues.Add("ten points", "Last Month")
```

Then bind the `DropDownList` to that collection:

```
ddlTimePeriod.DataSource = listValues
ddlTimePeriod.DataTextField = "Value"
dddlTimePeriodl.DataValueField = "Key"
ddlTimePeriod.DataBind()
```

That way your markup doesn't need to contain the data, just the element to hold the data:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimePeriod" runat="server" CssClass="select" />
```

Comment: and i can just add that to the VB? in page load?

Comment: @bigdowg: Generally in `Page_Load`, but essentially wherever you want to populate the control with values.  Don't forget also to make sure it's not a post-back before populating the control, otherwise you'll lose whatever value was posted.

Comment: worked perfect great answer, i fixed the minor spelling errors :P